# Firebase child inside another child

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Can someone help me out with a firebase problem I am having, I want to add a child inside another child, I know this is simple, but since I am new to firebase, I will really appreciate any help regarding this, please let me know, if this question needs improvement in formatting, so that I can get better at stack overflow.

Adding item from this function

```
    public void addItem(Item model) {
    Item item = new Item();
    item.setItem(model.getItem());
    item.setPonum(model.getPonum());
    item.setQty(model.getQty());
    item.setSupplier(model.getSupplier());
    item.setContact(model.getContact());
    item.setTransporter(model.getTransporter());
    item.setLrnum(model.getLrnum());
    item.setRemarks(model.getRemarks());

    String key = mDatabase.child("Items").push().getKey();
    Map<String, Object> postValues = item.toMap();

    Map<String, Object> childUpdates = new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put(key, postValues);
    mDatabase.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}
```

I need exception only for the remarks section, I will upload pics of what exactly I have in mind, below image is what I currently have, I want the database like the second image [image: What I currently have]

[image: What I Need]

Comment: What exception you are getting

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't get you, I am not getting any errors, I just want to add the remarks child in my original database, with a new comment added everyone someone updates. I am just not sure, how to so this.

P.S There is no authentication, anyone can update the database.

Comment: What is the type of `remarks` in `Item`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your `Item` object should look like this:

```
public class Item {

    private String contact;
    private String item;
    private String lrnum;
    private String ponum;
    private String qty;
    private HashMap<String, String> remarks;
    private String supplier;
    private String transporter;

    // ... you configure setting method by setter or constructor, your choice

    public String getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public String getItem() {
        return item;
    }

    public String getLrnum() {
        return lrnum;
    }

    public String getPonum() {
        return ponum;
    }

    public String getQty() {
        return qty;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getRemarks() {
        return remarks;
    }

    public String getSupplier() {
        return supplier;
    }

    public String getTransporter() {
        return transporter;
    }

    // and maybe add this to easily add one remarks
    public void addRemark(String remarkKey, String remark) {
        if (remarks == null)
            remarks = new HashMap<>();

        remarks.put(remarkKey, remark);
    }
}
```

Then you only need this lines of code to insert it into your Firebase database:

```
public void addItem(Item model) {
    mDatabase.child("Items").push().setValue(model);
}
```

Comment: this should place your new `Item` inside `Items` node of your database, if you want it inside `uniabex-a22fb` node, just replace `child("Items")` with `child("uniabex-a22fb")`. But you get the idea

Comment: Thank you, I'll update if I need any further assistance on this.

Answer (score 1):

Get a reference of your Node where you have to push new data.

```
Firebase newRef = ref.child("Key_of_root_node").child("remarks_parent_node").child("remarks").push();
newRef.setValue("Hi I am Comment");
```

Push will generate key for you, so no need to do handling for generating keys like Comment1, Comment2.

Comment: I tried doing this, but in vain, could you please help me out with it, I have tried to make this app using a tutorial, I am also new to android, I am making only small apps, this app is kinda tricky for, hope you understand, please help me out https://github.com/fayazara/Uniabex-Materials

Comment: Just call above code from where you trying to add remarks. Its hard for me to track in your code that from where you are executing it